# Problemas com modal/boostrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Olá, estou com um problema no meu site, gostaria que quando eu clicasse no botão do modal, ele fechasse e abrisse o modal novamente(o código a seguir é um código resumido do que eu necessito), neste código, quando eu abro a página o modal abre automaticamente, e quando eu clico no botao close, ele fecha e abre, porém, quando faço isso duas vezes, o modal simplesmente não abre mais e a tela fica toda preta e travada.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" onclick="functiona()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
<?php
      $IdUsuario = $_GET['IdUsuario'];
      $senhaConfere = "nao"

      if (isset($senhaConfere)) {
        if ($senhaConfere=="nao") { 
          echo $senhaConfere;
          ?>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
          </script>
    <?php
        }
      }                
    ?>
}
?>
<script>
function functiona(){
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#myModal').modal('hide');
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
 });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Alguém já teve esse problema, ou sabe como resolver?
Grato desde já!

Comment: Ás vezes o problema está na inserção de arquivos JS do Bootstrap,verifique o console do seu navegador pode estar faltando algum import e aparentemente seu código está com duas declarações de Bootstrap o que pode esta ocasionando esse conflito!

Comment: Quando você fecha o modal ele tem de abrir logo de novo de imediato ? então porque permitir ele fechar ?

Comment: @EricRosário valeu, vou verificar.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, você não pode colocar tudo na mesma função, por que você tá usando a mesma para ocultar e exibir chame-as separadamente, tente fazer da seguinte forma:

```
   <script>
        function ocultar(){
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
     });
        </script>
```

Comment: Valeu, vou tentar assim mesmo, quando chegar no local aviso se funciona

Comment: Infelizmente o problema persiste.